# run "npm run build" with only "dotnet run"

Tags: asp.net, vue.js

so I make it quick.
I have an ASP.NET framework running with a VueJS-Project in it.
So I want to run "npm install" and "npm run build" inside the VueJS-folder with only the "dotnet run" command for starting the ASP.NET. 
I already configured that "npm run build" is building the files into the wwwroot/client-app of the ASP.NET-project but I have to run the build command everytime before running the dotnet command.
I tried to add some code to the csproj but it doesn't worked. That means he isn't updating the files in wwwroot.

This is what I added to my csproj-file:

```
<Target Name="client-app" BeforeTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="client-app"></Exec>
    <Exec Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="client-app"></Exec>
</Target>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with the problem even though I may be quite wrong.
So the short version: I want that if I run dotnet run also the both commands npm install and run build are going to be executed without run them separately

Thx
ApFrePs

Comment: Can you describe more?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get (***i suppose you are using visual studio code***) is [creating a task](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) that does that.

```
{
  "label": "build webapp",
  "command": "dotnet build ${workspaceFolder}/(project-name)/(project-name).csproj && npm install && npm build",
  "type": "shell",
  "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
}
```

Then you can [attach the task to launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) like:

```
{
  "name": "Development: .NET Core Launch (web)",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build webapp" // <- THIS IS THE NAME OF THE TASK
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
}
```